# error C4700: uninitialized local variable; How to initialize it in MFC application

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, initialization

Here is the little part of my code, I'm trying to convert my string operants into integer when I need it with the `atoi`. And I am encountering an error "*uninitialized local variable* ". How could I fix this problem?

```
CDC * pDC = GetDC();
CSize cz;

input1.GetWindowTextW(operant1);
input2.GetWindowTextW(operant2);

combo.GetWindowTextW(advanced_text);

if(groupCheckRadio == 0){        //AND
    const char* operant1;
    const char* operant2;

    int num1 = atoi(operant1);
    int num2 = atoi(operant2);

    result = (num1 & num2);

}
if(groupCheckRadio == 1){        //OR
    const char* operant1;
    const char* operant2;

    int num1 = atoi(operant1);
    int num2 = atoi(operant2);

    result = (num1 | num2);

}
if(groupCheckRadio == 2){        //XOR
    const char* operant1;
    const char* operant2;

    int num1 = atoi(operant1);
    int num2 = atoi(operant2);

    result = (num1 ^ num2);

}

//shifting bits
if(checkShift.GetCheck() == 1){
    int selected_index = combo.GetCurSel();
    combo.GetLBText(selected_index,advanced_text);
}
```

Comment: Why do you have the `const char* operant1;` (and ...2) lines *inside* the `if` blocks. They should be outside and *before* the calls to `GetWindowText`. They also need to be pointers to something valid (allocated) or `char[]` arrays.

Comment: There are other errors in your code, too. Consider posting a more complete example and I'll consider posting a more complete answer.

Comment: Where do `operant1` and `operant2` point to?

Comment: This is trying way too hard to do, what MFC does for you already. You can use the [`DDX_Text`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/standard-dialog-data-exchange-routines#ddx_text) dialog data exchange function to map an edit control to an `int` value. If that is too much black magic, there's [`GetDlgItemInt`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdlgitemint) as well, that does the same, plus error reporting.

Comment: Hello guys, thank you all for your answers. I have solved my problem using _ttof. After that I changed my double to integer.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone If anyone wants to convert Cstring to integer after that, they can solve it using **_ttof**

```
CString  operant1,operant2,bit,advanced_text,result,num_bin;
double numd1,numd2,resultd,bind,numdbin;


input1.GetWindowTextW(operant1);
input2.GetWindowTextW(operant2);
combo.GetWindowTextW(advanced_text);
input_bit.GetWindowTextW(num_bin);

CDC * pDC = GetDC();
CSize cz;   
cz = pDC->GetTextExtent(result);  

resultd = _ttof(result);
numd1 = _ttof(operant1);
numd2 = _ttof(operant2);


unsigned int resulti = int (resultd);
unsigned int num1 = int (numd1);
unsigned int num2 = int (numd2);
```

''

Comment: While this may solve your immediate issue, it neither explains what the issue with the code in the question is, nor how to solve *that* issue. Please take the [tour] to learn what Stack Overflow is.